# Javascript array with index Number.MAX_VALUE

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can anybody please explain this behavior of javascript arrays

```
//create an empty array
var arr=[];

//added an entry with index Number.MAX_VALUE
arr[Number.MAX_VALUE]="test"

//On printing the array, its showing as empty
arr
//[]

//even its length=0
arr.length
//0

//on accessing the same value its showing the correct value
arr[Number.MAX_VALUE]
//"test"
```

I have tried this with Number.MIN_VALUE.

Does anybody know the reason behind this?

Comment: `Number.MAX_VALUE` is larger than the largest integer that can be an numeric array index, so it doesn't create an element or change the `.length`, but it does add a property. If you expand the array in the console you should see the property with the actual name that was set (I see the string `"1.7976931348623157e+308"`).

Comment: Incidentally, the same thing happens `1.5` or any other floating point number.

Comment: It also happens with any negative number so the behavior with `Number.MIN_VALUE` is not a surprise.

Comment: Arrays are proper Objects in JS and what you are doing is just assigning a '"1.7976931348623157e+308"' property with a value of '"test'" to your array. This property can not be interpreted as a index key type property. So it won't trigger the magical length property to increment.

Answer (score 7):

`Number.MAX_VALUE` is not a valid array index. [According to the spec:](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-type)

> An integer index is a String-valued property key that is a canonical numeric String (see 7.1.16) and whose numeric value is either +0 or a positive integer ≤ 2<sup>53</sup>-1. **An array index is an integer index whose numeric value i is in the range +0 ≤ i < 2<sup>32</sup>−1.**

Any property name that’s not an array index according to this definition is just a regular property name, as you can see by the key ordering (array indexes are in order; other properties are in insertion order):

```
var a = {};
a.prop = 'foo';
a[2 ** 32 - 2] = 'bar';
a[Number.MAX_VALUE] = 'baz';
console.log(Object.keys(a));
// ["4294967294", "prop", "1.7976931348623157e+308"]
```

Comment: Maybe mention that it creates a regular object property instead?

Answer (score -1):

It takes Number.MAX_VALUE not like an index, but like a property name. 
You can see same behavior for any string value

> A property name P (in the form of a string
>   value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to (2^32)−1

(http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf page65, section 15.4)

Comment: But...`Number.MAX_VALUE` is a number, not a string.

Comment: Ryan gave a nice explanation why it happens. MAX_VALUE is a number, yes, but array can't use it as an index.

Comment: Yes, I know what's happening, I just think you could've been clearer...

Comment: Arrays are not indexed by numbers, they are indexed by strings that have to be same after conversion string to number and resulted number to string. After such conversion that string must be the same. Saying simpler, they are indexed by string with number inside.